# How do I add a newline to flash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add line breaks in what gets put into flash. I have this simple code in a controller that I got from another question (an old one), but it's not working:

```
msg = ["what", "dude"]
flash.notice = msg.join("<br/>").html_safe
```

This is what gets displayed:

```
what<br/>dude
```

Did something change in rails? Or what am I missing?

Comment: `msg.join("<br/>".html_safe)` ?

Comment: @smathy nope, that doesn't work either. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle it when flash message is rendered. Flash messages are stored in your `session` cookie during a redirect and "HTML safeness" doesn't transfer over the cookies.

```rb
flash.notice = ["what", "dude"].join("<br>")
```

```rb
<%= flash.notice.html_safe %>
```

You could also add a new line:

```rb
flash.notice = ["what", "dude"].join("\n")
```

```html
<div style="white-space: pre-line;"><%= flash.notice %></div>
```